# Sorting in descending order of list

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have a list

```
m = {{a, 20}, {b, 10}, {c, 50}, {d, 5}, {e, 100}}
```

and I want to apply `Sort` on this in descending order on numbers only so that it looks like this

```
m = {{e, 100}, {c, 50}, {a, 20}, {b, 10}, {d, 5}}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Take a look at `SortBy`.

Comment: `SortBy[m,Last]`

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e it is easily found in the documentation and is unlikely to help any future visitors. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397).

Answer (score 10):

### Data

```
m = {{a, 20}, {b, 10}, {c, 50}, {d, 5} , {e, 100}}
```

### Code

```
Reverse[SortBy[m, Last]]
```

or

```
SortBy[m, Minus@*Last]
```

or since *Mathematica v12*

```
ReverseSortBy[Last][m]
```

> ```
> {{e, 100}, {c, 50}, {a, 20}, {b, 10}, {d, 5}}
> ```

Where `@*` stands for [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html)