# How to maintain the names of variables in lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this code that gives me all possible coalitions after the Dutch elections of maximum 4 political parties. However, the output is given in numbers. I would rather have the output in the names of the parties. How do I do it?

```
VVD = 33;
PVDA = 9;
PVV = 20;
SP = 14;
CDA = 19;
D66 = 19;
ChristenUnie = 5;
GroenLinks = 14;
SGP = 3;
PVDD = 5;
VPLUS = 4;
DENK = 3;
FVD = 2;

Lijst := {VVD, PVDA, PVV, SP, CDA, D66, ChristenUnie, GroenLinks, SGP,
   PVDD, VPLUS, DENK, FVD}

Select[Subsets[Lijst], Total[#] > 75 && Length[#] <= 4 &]
```

Comment: Is this topic enough [**70250**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70250/5478)? also related: [40663](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40663/5478)

Comment: I take issue with the premise of your question.  Why don't you use an association instead of variables?  What are you trying to achieve in the end?  I believe that in most cases doing this would be a misuse of the *variable* paradigm.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok, I changed my question to what I really want to know ;-)

Comment: @Szabolcs What I try to do in the end is show which coalitions are possible. You suggest using an association? How would that work then?

Comment: Same as your original example except you use `mylist = <|"a"->1, "b"->5, "c"->7|>`.  For this application variables are not appropriate.  Instead, bundle the name and the value together into one data structure.  That can be `{"name", value}`, `"name" -> value`, an association like above, etc. There are lots of choices.  Variables are about the worst possibility.

Comment: @Szabolcs How do I get Subsets to get to accept an Association?

Comment: Just for fun: `SortBy[(Select[
      Thread[# -> Total[#[[All, All, 2]], {2}] ], #[[2]] > 75 &] &@
    Subsets[list, 4]), Minus@*Last] // TableForm` where list = {{VVD, 33}, {PVDA, 9}, {PVV, 20}, {SP, 14}, {CDA, 19}, {D66, 
   19}, {ChristenUnie, 5}, {GroenLinks, 14}, {SGP, 3}, {PVDD, 
   5}, {VPLUS, 4}, {DENK, 3}, {FVD, 2}}

Comment: More fun: `Subsets[list, 4] // Thread[# -> Total[#[[All, All, 2]], {2}] ] & // 
   Select[#, #[[2]] > 75 &] & // SortBy[#, Minus@*Last] & // TableForm`. list as before

Comment: @tomd Nice! What does this mean Minus@*Last? How does it work?

Comment: `@*` is [Composition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) and `Minus@*Last` allows a reverse-order sort.  There is a [very nice post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97014/106) by [rhermans](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/10397/rhermans) who explains things better than I can. (I think my code can be improved!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example

```
a = <|"VVD" -> 33, "PVDA" -> 9, "PVV" -> 20, "SP" -> 14, 
   "CDA" -> 19, "D66" -> 19, "ChristenUnie" -> 5, "GroenLinks" -> 14, 
   "SGP" -> 3, "PVDD" -> 5, "VPLUS" -> 4, "DENK" -> 3, "FVD" -> 2|>;

Select[Subsets[Keys[a], {4}], Total[a[[#]]] == 75 &]

(* {{"VVD", "PVDA", "SP", "CDA"}, {"VVD", "PVDA", "SP", 
  "D66"}, {"VVD", "PVDA", "CDA", "GroenLinks"}, {"VVD", "PVDA", "D66",
   "GroenLinks"}, {"VVD", "PVV", "CDA", "SGP"}, {"VVD", "PVV", "CDA", 
  "DENK"}, {"VVD", "PVV", "D66", "SGP"}, {"VVD", "PVV", "D66", 
  "DENK"}, {"VVD", "CDA", "D66", "VPLUS"}} *)
```